# System.Threading.Timer Check if running

Tags: c#, timer

Is there a way to check if System.Threading.Timer is running. For example:

```
private Timer m_timer = new Timer( OnTimerCallback );

private void EnsureTimer()
{
    if( some check if timer is not running )
    {
        m_timer.Change( 30000, Timeout.Infinite );
    }
}
```

What should I put instead of `some check if timer is not running`

Comment: What do you mean by "running"? Timer enabled or if it is running the Callback method?

Comment: @Pikoh Timer enabled.

Comment: Create the Timer object only when you *need* it to be running and it turns into a simple null check.

Comment: If you don't want to switch to [`System.Timers.Timer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer(v=vs.110).aspx) you'll have to keep track of its *enabled* state your self. Do what Hans suggests

Comment: @HansPassant good idea I'll probably end up using it like that.

Answer (score -3):

You should be **using Timer from System.Timers dll**(not System.Threading dll) and then easily use its methods like **.Enabled and .Elapsed** to complete your functionality.

Also, it is **thread safe**.

Comment: Sorry but it's not an option to use System.Timers.Timer instead.